# instance.render is not a function error in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a very unusual error in reactjs and it says that instance.render is not a function in reactjs .I couldn't trace the error .
Here is the index.js file and the only other file that i have in component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar.js';
const API_KEY='AIzaSyA4c4bzl1At2c0IAJXU939D1vAIUwAn3Ss';
const App = ()=>{
  return(
     <div>
      <SearchBar/>
     </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is search_bar.js in Searchbar in components folder .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class SearchBar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={
       term:''
     };
     this.onInputchange=this.onInputchange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputchange(event){
   console.log(event);
  }
  render(){
     return(
        <div className="search_bar">
         <input
             onChange={this.onInputchange}
         />
         </div>
     );
   }

}
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Mark as answered if this did the job for you :]

Comment: I have recreated your app here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k35pq015zv and it appears to work fine. Could you try removing the css import locally and see if that makes a difference? Are you able to show us the exact error? is there any more code involved that you have not shared?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is occuring with your App element. Either call the function or try structuring it like a React Cmopnent and that should fix it. Worked for me in Code Pen

```js
class App extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
      return(
       <div>
        <SearchBar/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It's trying to call render on your `App` because you structured it like a React JSX Component. But in reality it's a function. You can also just call App instead of setting it up like JSX

`ReactDOM.render(App(), document.getElementById('root'));`

But I'd stick with the first method. Easier to understand what's going on

Comment: I actually don't think this is the root cause of his problem, defining his App component using an arrow function is valid syntax in this scenario. Using a class is just an alternative way of doing it

Comment: But than wrapping the arrow function in JSX and trying to pass it into `ReactDom.render` is where the flaw is. There's nothing wrong with passing an arrow function. as the parameter. But it should've been called instead of wrapped in JSX. That part doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Imagine `let someFunction = () => return(<h1>HelloWorld</h1>);` Followed by `ReactDOM.render(<somefunction />, document.getElementById('root'));`. If you continued reading the bottom of my post, you would've seen that I also provided the correct usage of an arrow function for rendering.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the same problem. one way to work around this is using normal JavaScript prototype method. I have used react without es6 to find the fault.

```js
var MyApp = function(){
    React.Component.call(this);
    //below it create intances:
    /*this.render =  function (){
        return React.createElement('div', null, "it is working");
   };*/
   
};

MyApp.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);
MyApp.prototype.constructor = MyApp;
//below i create a prototype method on the class

MyApp.prototype.render = function(){
    return React.createElement('div', null, "hoo");
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyApp), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</body>
```